# Reading a log file which gets rolled over

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

I am trying to use a simple program to read from a log file. The code used is as follows:

```
RandomAccessFile in = new RandomAccessFile("/home/hduser/Documents/Sample.txt", "r");
String line;
while(true) {
if((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(line);
} else {
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

The code works well for new lines being added to the log file but it does not replicate the rollover process. i.e. when the content of the log file is cleared I expect the java console to continue reading text from the first line newly written to the log. Could that be possible? What changes need to be made to the existing code to achieve that?

Comment: *"when the content of the log file is cleared I expect the java console to go blank as well"*  What on Earth would make you expect that?

Comment: I am sorry... My Bad.. I don't want it to go blank.. I just want the next new line written to the log to be read.

Comment: I think you mean that the log file will be erased, and you want to read the next line written to it.  You'll need to open the file again.  Most likely you'll get a read error once the file is trashed.  Try my approach of repeatedly closing and opening the file, remembering your last position.  If the file size is smaller than your last position, the file has been rolled over.  In my answer I have more details about doing this in a more robust way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I am sorry... My Bad.. I don't want it to go blank.. I just want the next new line written to the log to be read.`

Since what you need is able to read from beginning when you file is cleared, you will need to monitor the length of file and reset the cursor pointer when length of file reduces. You can reset the cursor using `seek(..)` method.

See code below -

```
RandomAccessFile in = new RandomAccessFile("/home/hduser/Documents/Sample.txt", "r");
String line;
long length = 0;//used to check the file length
while (true) {
    if(in.length()<length){//new condition to reset position if file length is reduced 
        in.seek(0);
    }
    if ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        length = in.length();
    } else {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: `seek` will not clear the console, `seek` will only reset the pointer. In above case, it will reset the pointer to 0. So any lines in new Sample.txt will be written on console.

Comment: actually, I had to modify the code a bit.. It is working for me... Thanks a ton!!

Comment: What happens if the reader is in the middle of the file reading and a rollover happened?

Answer (score 2):

At my work I had to deal with the processing of logs that can be rolled over without missing any data.  What I do is store a tiny memo file that contains:

- A hash of the first 1024 bytes (or less) of the log (I used SHA-1 or something because it's easy)
- The number of bytes used to generate the hash
- The current file position

I close the log file after processing all lines, or some maximum number of lines, and update the memo file.  I sleep for a tiny bit and then open the log file again.  This allows me to check whether a rollover has occurred.  A rollover is detected when:

1. The current file is smaller than the last file position
2. The hash is not the same

In my case, I can use the hash to find the correct log file, and work backwards to get up to date.  Once I know I've picked up where I left off in the correct file, I can continue reading and memoizing my position.  I don't know if this is relevant to what you want to do, but maybe that gives you ideas.

If you don't have any persistence requirements, you probably don't need to store any memo files.  If your 'rollover' just clears the log and doesn't move it away, you probably don't need to remember any file hashes.

Comment: Hey Paddy, thanks for your explanation. I am new to java and still trying to learn these concepts. Do you mean to say that the reopening of the file cannot be done with the RandomAccessFile class? My rollover would just clear the log and start writing from first line again.. So I need a java code which would read those logs without missing any log entry.

Comment: Well, normally you can't delete a file if someone else has it open.  So you must be erasing the contents (and maybe truncating?) without deleting.  That's okay, but you just need to detect it.  Your file pointer is not going to recognise when the file is rolled over.  You need to actually reposition it.  Maybe you can do this without closing the file, but it's a bit strange.  It's far more normal to rotate logs by renaming them, which you can only do if anyone who is reading them is being well-behaved (not holding it open).

Answer (score 0):

> it does not replicate the rollover process. i.e. when the content of the log file is cleared I expect the java console to continue reading text from the first line newly written to the log. Could that be possible?

Struggling with this as well.  +1 to @paddy for the hash idea.

Another solution (depending on your operating system) is to use the use the inode of the file although this may only work under unix:

```
Long inode = (Long)Files.getAttribute(logFile.toPath(), "unix:ino");
```

This returns the inode of the underlying file-system associated with log-file.  If the inode changes then the file is a brand new file.  This assumes when the log is rolled over that it is moved aside and the same file is not written over.

To make this work you would record the inode of the file you are reading then check to see if the inode has changed if you haven't gotten any new data in some period of time.